# Is there a way to prevent inline edit to update all fields on the layout?

Tags: page-layout, inlineeditsupport, standardlayout

On a standard object layout when you inline edit a single field, all the fields displayed on the layout are updated. Could be possible that only the field(s) that have been modified are updated?

Consider this scenario:

- You are using the Service Console

  - You have an Account open as primary tab
  - You have a Case related to the account, open as a sub tab
  - You close the case using the standard Close button
  - Upon the case closure, an apex trigger will update a field called Status on the account from value "OLD_VALUE" to "NEW_VALUE"
  - You go back to account primary tab, where the status field is still showing as "OLD_VALUE"
  - You inline edit ONLY the account description and Save

As a result, account Status value is again "OLD_VALUE". Saving the account record after an inline edit will override the Status field also (and all others present on layout).

Comment: Could replace the detail page with a visualforce page & do your own `onchange` actions. I tried this about a year ago and it ended up being very painful to maintain.

Comment: This is a problem related to your tabs not refreshng when the Case is updated after the trigger fires. I'd expect that your Account page SHOULD give you a message telling you the data has been changed BEFORE it allows you to save the record.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me and I have tested at my DE. You have a problem of tab refreshing.

**Solution**

In the console App configuration, change the following values as follows:

**Choose How Lists Refresh** = `Refresh List` (I think it has been configured as `None` at your org)

**Choose How Detail Pages Refresh** = `Automatically Refresh` (I think it has been configured as `Do Not Refresh` at your org).

Now, after saving the case record from the subtab, if you go to Account Primary tab, you will see the updated account status value.

So, before any inline edits you will always see updated Account value.

Here is the console App configuration.

[image: console]

Trigger code

```
trigger CaseTrigger2 on Case (after insert, after update) {
    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

    Map<String, String> accMap = New Map<String, String>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
        {
            accMap.put(caseObj.AccountId, caseObj.status);            
        }

        List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, Case_Status__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accMap.keySet()];
        for(Account acc:lstAccount)
        {
            acc.Case_Status__c = accMap.get(acc.Id);        
        }
        update lstAccount;
    }
}
```

Testing outcome

Here, changing the case status to `Cancelled` and just after saving navigating to Primary tab, Details - where I can see the updated Account's status as `Cancelled`

[image: Case status update]